# download file using RESTFUL Spring API in java

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have to download some files using RESTFUL Spring API in java. I have written API and it works fine if I use them directly on browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{tagCategory}/{query}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getResourceFile(@PathVariable String tagCategory, @PathVariable String query) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH + tagCategory + "/" + query + ".txt");

    if (file.exists())
        System.out.println(file.toString() + " exists");
    else
        System.out.println(file.toString() + "not exists");

    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + file.getName()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).contentLength(file.length())
            .body(resource);
}
```

Now, I want to make a wrapper( which I would use in my different project) which would call this API and get me the downloaded file.
The wrapper is like

```
@Override
public InputStreamResource getResourceFile(String tagCategory, String query) throws Exception
{
    Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    System.out.println("sdsdS12");
    HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>>(requestBody);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    CustomResponse<InputStreamResource> response = (CustomResponse<InputStreamResource>) performRestCall(
            "http://localhost:8080/SpringRestfulWebServicesExample/download/" + tagCategory + "/" + query, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomResponse<InputStreamResource>>()
            {});
    InputStreamResource isr = response.getPayload();
    File file = new File("C:/arpittandon.txt");
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(isr.getInputStream(), file);
    if (response.isSuccess())
        return response.getPayload();
    else
        throw new Exception(response.getMessage());
}
```

where CustomResponse is

```
public class CustomResponse<T>
{
private boolean success = true;
private String  message = "";
private T       payload;

public boolean isSuccess()
{
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success)
{
    this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage()
{
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message)
{
    this.message = message;
}

public T getPayload()
{
    return payload;
}

public void setPayload(T payload)
{
    this.payload = payload;
}
```

}

and  performRESTCall is

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
protected Object performRestCall(String url, HttpMethod httpMethod, HttpEntity body, ParameterizedTypeReference ptr)
{
    return performRestCall(url, httpMethod, body, ptr, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
protected Object performRestCall(String url, HttpMethod httpMethod, HttpEntity body, ParameterizedTypeReference ptr, int timeout)
{

    // System.out.println(url);
    // System.out.println(body.toString());
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    factory.setConnectTimeout(timeout);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);

    return restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, body, ptr).getBody();
}
```

When I call this, I get the following error

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'mesh_mh': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

I am not so good in java and using the above code as the template from the existing code.

I just need to download the file using the api in my different project. How can I do that

Comment: Your client's headers don't indicate that it's expecting an octet stream type.  I believe it's assuming that you're getting JSON back.

Comment: How to add that?

Comment: Try putting @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).